# Exclude blanks from grid but preserve order of values and their original column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

See picture or see this [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eOORepGsfmD91y1nhqOI8-S068xE5Ksl4XbkAcpfvB0/edit#gid=0)

Assuming the number of columns can change, how can I remove blank cells but keep the order and each value in the same column?

[image]

Comment: Is it a one time operation? or something that needs to be happening "live" continuously all the time?

Comment: @MattKing Thank you for asking. It is live. So no scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(A2:C&"♦",,10^7)),"(♦ )+|♦$","$1"),"♦ ",FALSE)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter()`, like this:

`=filter(A2:A8, len(A2:A8))`

See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eOORepGsfmD91y1nhqOI8-S068xE5Ksl4XbkAcpfvB0/edit#gid=572710893).

Comment: While this sort of works, it requires me to manually drag the formula to each column. Is there a way to do this assuming that the number of columns can always change?

Comment: Consider sharing _realistic-looking_ data in a new tab in your sample spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

To use an indefinite number of columns, you could use an Apps Script [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions). To achieve this, follow these steps:

- In your spreadsheet, select **Tools > Script editor** to open a script bound to your file.
- Copy this function in the script editor, and save the project (check inline comments):

```
function REMOVE_EMPTY(values) {
  values = values[0].map((_, colIndex) => values.map(row => row[colIndex])) // Transpose 2D array to handle each column
                    .filter(col => col[0].length) // Remove empty columns
                    .map(col => col.filter(String)) // Remove empty cells in each column
  const maxColLength = Math.max(...values.map(c => c.length)); // Get max column length
  values = values.map(col => col.concat(...new Array(maxColLength - col.length).fill(""))); // Make all columns have same length
  values = values[0].map((_, colIndex) => values.map(row => row[colIndex])); // Transpose 2D array back
  return values;
}
```

- Now, if you go back to your spreadsheet, you can use this function like any in-built one. You just have to provide the appropriate range (in this case, `2:7`) as function argument:

[image]

#### Reference:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: `.filter(Boolean)` will weed out `0` and `false` values. Use `.filter(String)`?